# Is Google's App Engine suited for transaction based systems

Tags: database, google-app-engine, transactions

I am building a web application that is currently PHP with MySQL. There is payment on the website so the db tables are InnoDB with transactions.

Can this type of application be implemented in Google's App Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Did you have a specific question about how to implement some part of it?

Comment: Yes when I look into the documentation I only see how it is done in python. But I am going to use an Java implementation. I haven't found any resources on what kind of syntax to use.

Comment: Do you have any comments on the stability of the system?

Comment: The Java docs are here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html . The system is stable and robust; transactions are, well, transactional.